# fastapi+pydantic query parameter checking for complex arguments

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

Based on [this API definition](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest), my api supports queries like:

```
GET http://my.api.url/posts?sort=["title","ASC"]&range=[0, 24]&filter={"q":"bar"}
```

where some of the checks needed are

- `sort[1]` is either `"asc"` or `"desc"` (case should not matter)
- `filter` has the key `"q"`. `filter` can have other keys.
- `range` is a list of two integers. `range[0]` is less then or equal to `range[1]`

In fastapi path definitions I currently define `filter`, `sort`, and `range` as strings as in the code below, convert them using json.loads, and do checks.

```
@r.get(
    "/users",
    response_model=List[User],
    response_model_exclude_none=True,
)
async def list_users(
    filter: Optional[str] = None,
    sort: Optional[str] = None,
    range: Optional[str] = None,
    ...
):
...
```

How can I use pydantic definitions for checks and API definition instead of just using `str`, such that checks are done by pydantic, and openapi schema definitions are more descriptive?

Comment: You can use a `Depends` to depend on a utilty function that receives a string, decodes the JSON and use `parse_obj` or `parse_obj_as` (depending on the root level structure of the request JSON) helper function from Pydantic to validate the submitted content against your basemodel.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do what you want. But FastAPI only allow sequence structures (list, tuples, set, sequence) for Query and Header params, so that `&filter={"q":"bar"}` it won't work on FastAPI at least for 0.75.0 version where I am working.

If you wish to support a Dictionary you should use POST method with Body params. And then you can wrap your values around a Pydantic model to support validation.

Below there are two ways to implement this in FastAPI.

Solution 1:

```py
class FilterModel(BaseModel):
    filter: dict
    
@router.post(
    "/posts"
)
async def list_users(
    filters: FilterModel,
    sort: Tuple[str, Literal["DESC", "ASC", "desc", "asc"]] = Query(("title", "ASC")),
    ranges: Tuple[int, int] = Query((0, 24))
) -> None:
    print(filters)
    print(sort)
    print(ranges)
    model = MyModel(sort=sort, range=ranges)
    print(model)
```

This will allow you to call api like:

```
POST http://my.api.url/posts?sort=title&sort=ASC&ranges=0&ranges=24
```

With body:

```
{
    "filter"={"q":"bar"}
}
```

Solution 2:

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    sortBy: Optional[str]
    sortOrder: Optional[Literal["DESC", "ASC", "desc", "asc"]]
    min_range: Optional[int]
    max_range: Optional[int]

class FilterModel(BaseModel):
    filter: dict

@router.post(
    "/posts"
)
async def list_users(
    filters: FilterModel,
    model: MyModel = Depends()
) -> None:
    print(filters)
    print(model)
```

This will allow you to call api like:

```
POST http://my.api.url/posts?sortBy="title"&sortOrder="ASC"&min_range=0&max_range=24
```

With body:

```
{
    "filter"={"q":"bar"}
}
```

If you wish to use GET method and the `filter` you have to do some hacky things.